# How to add time to Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add hours and minutes to date and My code is working fine in chrome but not working in firefox and internet explorer. Can any one tell me why?

```
   var d2=new Date(); 
   d2.setHours(d2.getHours()+24);
   d2.setMinutes(d2.getMinutes()+30);
```

Comment: Read up on javascript date here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: You are doing something wrong. That code works properly in most browsers.

Comment: What output are you getting? What error message? Your code works on IE 11

Comment: you asked the same question, I think.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309087/adding-time-to-date-in-javascript

Comment: Amnon  I am getting "invalid date" error messaga?

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox

Comment: I tested with Firefox  43.0.1 and IE 11 and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you could.

The code would be the following:

```
var d2 = moment();
d2.add(24, 'hours');
d2.add(30, 'minutes');
```

Comment: I want to add to existing date. What happens with var d2=new moment();

Comment: This should just work fine in plain JS. No need to load a whole library for just this.

Comment: putvande can you give me the solution ?

Comment: You can use: `moment('1900-02-23')` or `moment('23-03-1900', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: @ Serginho can you please tell me what do I need to do to use moment.js

Comment: Come on! Do you only read stackoverflow? You can download it from oficial website or include as script from github `https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.11.2/moment.js`